# is there any way to find the specific DNA sequence motif in FASTA data format file in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a question and it would be great if anybody who knows help me in it.
I have a big FASTA format file that contains FASTA sequence of the chip-seq peaks. I did motif analysis for my data and now I have many known motifs like FOXA1 or SP1 motif. But actually I want to know, in which position (peak) I have sequence of that specific motif. So, I have the sequence of the motif and I want to search this motif in my FASTA file to find where there is this sequence .
I hope i delivered the concept to you. This is completely new for me and I have'nt had any experiance in this issue.

```
df1<-data.frame(position=c( ">69366501",">69366750",">69368467",">69766890"),SEQ=c("GAAGGAGAAGGGGAGAGACTGGAAGAGAAGGAAGGAGCTTTGGG","AAGAGGGGAAAAGACCATAGCAGAGAGCTCAGCCTGACCACGG","AAGAGGGGAATTTGATAGCAGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGCACCACGG","GAAGGAGAAGGGGAGAGACTGGTATAGATGACCATAGGAAGGAGCTTTGGG"))
```

and for example the sequence that I want to search it and find it in my file is "AGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGC" so, I want to see that I have this motif sequence in my file or not and if yes, where is it, in whcih position.

- it is not exact file that I have but I think it is good to deliver my meaning.
  My main and original file is in FASTA format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `grep('AGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGC',df1$SEQ) 
[1] 3` or `grep('AGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGC',df1$SEQ, value = TRUE) 
[1] "AAGAGGGGAATTTGATAGCAGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGCACCACGG"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And noodling around in `base`, though @Fadel-Megahed's certainly seems easier... anticipating you might want position start of the embedded substring:

```
df2 <-data.frame(
  position=c( ">69366501",">69366750",">69368467",">69766890"),
  SEQ=c("GAAGGAGAAGGGGAGAGACTGGAAGAGAAGGAAGGAGCTTTGGG",
        "AAGAGGGGAAAAGACCATAGCAGAGAGCTCAGCCTGACCACGG",
        "AAGAGGGGAATTTGATAGCAGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGCACCACGG",
        "GAAGGAGAAGGGGAGAGACTGGTATAGATGACCATAGGAAGGAGCTTTGGG")
)

d2$position <- gsub('>', '', df2$position)
# what we're looking for in SEQ
term <- 'AGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGC'

strsplit(df2$SEQ, term, fixed = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "GAAGGAGAAGGGGAGAGACTGGAAGAGAAGGAAGGAGCTTTGGG"

[[2]]
[1] "AAGAGGGGAAAAGACCATAGCAGAGAGCTCAGCCTGACCACGG"

[[3]]
[1] "AAGAGGGGAATTTGATAGC" "ACCACGG"            

[[4]]
[1] "GAAGGAGAAGGGGAGAGACTGGTATAGATGACCATAGGAAGGAGCTTTGGG"

# only one string is split by `term`, SEQ[3] which is the same as our `grep(`
grep(term,df2$SEQ) 
[1] 3

nchar(unlist(strsplit(df2$SEQ[3], term, fixed = TRUE))[1])
[1] 19
nchar(term)
[1] 20
nchar(unlist(strsplit(df2$SEQ[3], term, fixed = TRUE))[2])
[1] 7
> nchar(df2$SEQ[3])
[1] 46
(nchar(unlist(strsplit(df2$SEQ[3], term, fixed = TRUE))[1]) + nchar(term) + nchar(unlist(strsplit(df2$SEQ[3], term, fixed = TRUE))[2]) == nchar(df2$SEQ[3]))
[1] TRUE
as.numeric(df2$position[3]) + as.numeric(nchar(unlist(strsplit(df2$SEQ[3], term, fixed = TRUE))[1]))
[1] 69368486 # which may well want +1 depending...
```

It is hard to imagine that `Bioconductor` doesn't have convenience utilities that anticipate these needs in the realm of `FASTA` data, and would be worth investigating.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Chris's point, if you are trying to find the location of the string within the SEQ column, this approach should work:

```
if( require(tidyverse) ==F ) install.packages('tidyverse'); library(tidyverse)

df1 <-data.frame(
  position=c( ">69366501",">69366750",">69368467",">69766890"),
  SEQ=c("GAAGGAGAAGGGGAGAGACTGGAAGAGAAGGAAGGAGCTTTGGG",
        "AAGAGGGGAAAAGACCATAGCAGAGAGCTCAGCCTGACCACGG",
        "AAGAGGGGAATTTGATAGCAGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGCACCACGG",
        "GAAGGAGAAGGGGAGAGACTGGTATAGATGACCATAGGAAGGAGCTTTGGG")
)

df1$SEQ %>% stringr::str_locate(pattern = "AGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGC")
```

And here is the solution output, which shows that this pattern only existed in the third column and it started at character 20 and ended at character 39, which makes sense since `nchar("AGTGCAGCTAGCTAGCGGGC")` would return 20 (i.e., 39-20+1).

[image]

Comment: As 'cut and paste' for testing out code is fairly common, you might want to edit out your `>` and `+` above to avoid...